# How do I fill in missing dates by group in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have the following table in Oracle SQL:

```
+------------+-------+
| COLOR_DATE | COLOR |
+------------+-------+
| 28-Jan-20  | red   |
| 3-Feb-20   | red   |
| 6-Feb-20   | red   |
| 16-Apr-20  | blue  |
| 19-Apr-20  | blue  |
| 23-Apr-20  | blue  |
| 2-May-20   | blue  |
+------------+-------+
```

I want to fill in the missing dates based on `COLOR`. That is, I want to get min date and max date for each `COLOR` and generate rows with missing dates filled in. The resulting table will look like the following:

```
+------------+-------+
| COLOR_DATE | COLOR |
+------------+-------+
| 28-Jan-20  | red   |
| 29-Jan-20  | red   |
| 30-Jan-20  | red   |
| 31-Jan-20  | red   |
| 1-Feb-20   | red   |
| 2-Feb-20   | red   |
| 3-Feb-20   | red   |
| 4-Feb-20   | red   |
| 5-Feb-20   | red   |
| 6-Feb-20   | red   |
| 16-Apr-20  | blue  |
| 17-Apr-20  | blue  |
| 18-Apr-20  | blue  |
| 19-Apr-20  | blue  |
| 20-Apr-20  | blue  |
| 21-Apr-20  | blue  |
| 22-Apr-20  | blue  |
| 23-Apr-20  | blue  |
| 24-Apr-20  | blue  |
| 25-Apr-20  | blue  |
| 26-Apr-20  | blue  |
| 27-Apr-20  | blue  |
| 28-Apr-20  | blue  |
| 29-Apr-20  | blue  |
| 30-Apr-20  | blue  |
| 1-May-20   | blue  |
| 2-May-20   | blue  |
+------------+-------+
```

Please note that there will be indefinite number of `COLOR`s.

Can someone show me how to do this in Oracle SQL?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Below is the sql query to generate the table in Oracle for your convenience:

```
with a as (
            select to_date('1/28/2020 11:51', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') as color_date
                   ,  'red' as color   
                   from dual
            union
            select to_date('2/3/2020 11:51', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') as color_date
                   ,  'red' as color  
                   from dual
            union
            select to_date('2/6/2020 11:51', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') as color_date
                   ,  'red' as color  
                   from dual
            union
            select to_date('4/16/2020 11:51', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') as color_date
                   ,  'blue' as color   
                   from dual
            union
            select to_date('4/19/2020 11:51', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') as color_date
                   ,  'blue' as color  
                   from dual
            union
            select to_date('4/23/2020 11:51', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') as color_date
                   ,  'blue' as color  
                   from dual
            union
            select to_date('5/2/2020 11:51', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') as color_date
                   ,  'blue' as color  
                   from dual
                )
select *
from a
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Recursive Subquery Factoring](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#BABCDJDB) to generate intervals:

```
with tbl as (
    select to_date('1/28/2020 11:51', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') as color_date, 'red' as color  from dual union
    select to_date('2/3/2020 11:51', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') as color_date,  'red' as color  from dual union
    select to_date('2/6/2020 11:51', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') as color_date,  'red' as color  from dual union
    select to_date('4/16/2020 11:51', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') as color_date, 'blue' as color from dual union
    select to_date('4/19/2020 11:51', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') as color_date, 'blue' as color from dual union
    select to_date('4/23/2020 11:51', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') as color_date, 'blue' as color from dual union
    select to_date('5/2/2020 11:51', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') as color_date,  'blue' as color from dual
),
tbl_min_max as (
    select t.color, min(trunc(color_date)) begin_interval, max(trunc(color_date)) end_interval from tbl t group by t.color
),
tbl_interval(color, begin_interval, end_interval, color_date) as (
    select color, begin_interval, end_interval, begin_interval from tbl_min_max
    union all 
    select color, begin_interval, end_interval, color_date + 1 from tbl_interval where color_date < end_interval 
)
select 
    t.color, t.color_date
from 
    tbl_interval t
order by
    t.color, t.color_date
```