# How do I fill in missing dates by group in Oracle with changing count value

Tags: oracle

This is a slight modification to a question I posted previously:
[How do I fill in missing dates by group in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63002363/how-do-i-fill-in-missing-dates-by-group-in-oracle)

I have the following table in Oracle SQL:

```
+-----------+-------+-------+
|   Date    | Color | Count |
+-----------+-------+-------+
| 16-Jan-20 | blue  |     7 |
| 19-Jan-20 | blue  |    32 |
| 23-Jan-20 | blue  |    16 |
| 28-Jan-20 | blue  |    24 |
| 31-Jan-20 | blue  |    41 |
| 2-Feb-20  | blue  |    11 |
| 28-Jan-20 | red   |     1 |
| 3-Feb-20  | red   |     5 |
| 6-Feb-20  | red   |    11 |
| 11-Feb-20 | red   |     4 |
| 15-Feb-20 | red   |     6 |
+-----------+-------+-------+
```

What I want to do is for each `color`, fill in the missing dates from January 1, 2020 to February 29, 2020. In doing so, I want to use the `COUNT` column in the following way:

1. Get the `COUNT` for a `COLOR` in a forward-fill manner. For example, in my table, January 17, 2020 is missing for `BLUE`. I will fill in the `COUNT` for January 17, 2020 with 7 because it is the latest available count for that color. Similarly, for January 22, 2020, for `BLUE`, I will fill in 32 for `COUNT`.
2. If there is no `COUNT` value that exist before the given date, then fill in the `COUNT` value with the earlierst `COUNT` value available. For example, for January 2, 2020, `COUNT` value will be 7 for `BLUE`.

The resulting table is below:

```
+-----------+-------+-------+
|   Date    | Color | Count |
+-----------+-------+-------+
| 1-Jan-20  | blue  |     7 |
| 2-Jan-20  | blue  |     7 |
| 3-Jan-20  | blue  |     7 |
| 4-Jan-20  | blue  |     7 |
| 5-Jan-20  | blue  |     7 |
| 6-Jan-20  | blue  |     7 |
| 7-Jan-20  | blue  |     7 |
| 8-Jan-20  | blue  |     7 |
| 9-Jan-20  | blue  |     7 |
| 10-Jan-20 | blue  |     7 |
| 11-Jan-20 | blue  |     7 |
| 12-Jan-20 | blue  |     7 |
| 13-Jan-20 | blue  |     7 |
| 14-Jan-20 | blue  |     7 |
| 15-Jan-20 | blue  |     7 |
| 16-Jan-20 | blue  |     7 |
| 17-Jan-20 | blue  |     7 |
| 18-Jan-20 | blue  |     7 |
| 19-Jan-20 | blue  |    32 |
| 20-Jan-20 | blue  |    32 |
| 21-Jan-20 | blue  |    32 |
| 22-Jan-20 | blue  |    32 |
| 23-Jan-20 | blue  |    16 |
| 24-Jan-20 | blue  |    16 |
| 25-Jan-20 | blue  |    16 |
| 26-Jan-20 | blue  |    16 |
| 27-Jan-20 | blue  |    16 |
| 28-Jan-20 | blue  |    24 |
| 29-Jan-20 | blue  |    24 |
| 30-Jan-20 | blue  |    24 |
| 31-Jan-20 | blue  |    41 |
| 1-Feb-20  | blue  |    41 |
| 2-Feb-20  | blue  |    11 |
| 3-Feb-20  | blue  |    11 |
| 4-Feb-20  | blue  |    11 |
| 5-Feb-20  | blue  |    11 |
| 6-Feb-20  | blue  |    11 |
| 7-Feb-20  | blue  |    11 |
| 8-Feb-20  | blue  |    11 |
| 9-Feb-20  | blue  |    11 |
| 10-Feb-20 | blue  |    11 |
| 11-Feb-20 | blue  |    11 |
| 12-Feb-20 | blue  |    11 |
| 13-Feb-20 | blue  |    11 |
| 14-Feb-20 | blue  |    11 |
| 15-Feb-20 | blue  |    11 |
| 16-Feb-20 | blue  |    11 |
| 17-Feb-20 | blue  |    11 |
| 18-Feb-20 | blue  |    11 |
| 19-Feb-20 | blue  |    11 |
| 20-Feb-20 | blue  |    11 |
| 21-Feb-20 | blue  |    11 |
| 22-Feb-20 | blue  |    11 |
| 23-Feb-20 | blue  |    11 |
| 24-Feb-20 | blue  |    11 |
| 25-Feb-20 | blue  |    11 |
| 26-Feb-20 | blue  |    11 |
| 27-Feb-20 | blue  |    11 |
| 28-Feb-20 | blue  |    11 |
| 29-Feb-20 | blue  |    11 |
| 1-Jan-20  | red   |     1 |
| 2-Jan-20  | red   |     1 |
| 3-Jan-20  | red   |     1 |
| 4-Jan-20  | red   |     1 |
| 5-Jan-20  | red   |     1 |
| 6-Jan-20  | red   |     1 |
| 7-Jan-20  | red   |     1 |
| 8-Jan-20  | red   |     1 |
| 9-Jan-20  | red   |     1 |
| 10-Jan-20 | red   |     1 |
| 11-Jan-20 | red   |     1 |
| 12-Jan-20 | red   |     1 |
| 13-Jan-20 | red   |     1 |
| 14-Jan-20 | red   |     1 |
| 15-Jan-20 | red   |     1 |
| 16-Jan-20 | red   |     1 |
| 17-Jan-20 | red   |     1 |
| 18-Jan-20 | red   |     1 |
| 19-Jan-20 | red   |     1 |
| 20-Jan-20 | red   |     1 |
| 21-Jan-20 | red   |     1 |
| 22-Jan-20 | red   |     1 |
| 23-Jan-20 | red   |     1 |
| 24-Jan-20 | red   |     1 |
| 25-Jan-20 | red   |     1 |
| 26-Jan-20 | red   |     1 |
| 27-Jan-20 | red   |     1 |
| 28-Jan-20 | red   |     1 |
| 29-Jan-20 | red   |     1 |
| 30-Jan-20 | red   |     1 |
| 31-Jan-20 | red   |     1 |
| 1-Feb-20  | red   |     1 |
| 2-Feb-20  | red   |     1 |
| 3-Feb-20  | red   |     5 |
| 4-Feb-20  | red   |     5 |
| 5-Feb-20  | red   |     5 |
| 6-Feb-20  | red   |    11 |
| 7-Feb-20  | red   |    11 |
| 8-Feb-20  | red   |    11 |
| 9-Feb-20  | red   |    11 |
| 10-Feb-20 | red   |    11 |
| 11-Feb-20 | red   |     4 |
| 12-Feb-20 | red   |     4 |
| 13-Feb-20 | red   |     4 |
| 14-Feb-20 | red   |     4 |
| 15-Feb-20 | red   |     6 |
| 16-Feb-20 | red   |     6 |
| 17-Feb-20 | red   |     6 |
| 18-Feb-20 | red   |     6 |
| 19-Feb-20 | red   |     6 |
| 20-Feb-20 | red   |     6 |
| 21-Feb-20 | red   |     6 |
| 22-Feb-20 | red   |     6 |
| 23-Feb-20 | red   |     6 |
| 24-Feb-20 | red   |     6 |
| 25-Feb-20 | red   |     6 |
| 26-Feb-20 | red   |     6 |
| 27-Feb-20 | red   |     6 |
| 28-Feb-20 | red   |     6 |
| 29-Feb-20 | red   |     6 |
+-----------+-------+-------+
```

Please note that there will be indefinite number of `COLOR`s. The `COLOR_COUNT` will change unpredictably as well.

Can someone show me how to do this in Oracle SQL?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Below is the sql query to generate the table in Oracle for your convenience:

```
with tbl as (
    select to_date('1/28/2020 09:29', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') as color_date, 'red' as color,  1 color_count from dual union
    select to_date('2/3/2020 07:04', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') as color_date,  'red' as color,  5 color_count from dual union
    select to_date('2/6/2020 12:11', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') as color_date,  'red' as color,  11 color_count from dual union
    select to_date('2/11/2020 17:15', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') as color_date,  'red' as color,  4 color_count from dual union
    select to_date('2/15/2020 03:46', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') as color_date,  'red' as color,  6 color_count from dual union
    select to_date('1/16/2020 14:52', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') as color_date, 'blue' as color, 7 color_count from dual union
    select to_date('1/19/2020 22:30', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') as color_date, 'blue' as color, 32 color_count from dual union
    select to_date('1/23/2020 05:17', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') as color_date, 'blue' as color, 16 color_count from dual union
    select to_date('1/28/2020 18:35', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') as color_date, 'blue' as color, 24 color_count from dual union
    select to_date('1/31/2020 15:38', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') as color_date, 'blue' as color, 41 color_count from dual union
    select to_date('2/2/2020 16:01', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') as color_date,  'blue' as color, 11 color_count from dual
)
select *
from tbl
order by color, color_date
```

Comment: A couple of questions: 1. why do you really need this? Probably it would be better to write final required query without transient transformations

Comment: 2 How do you determine start date for this? Whould it be always 1st of Jan of the earliest year?

Comment: And 3rd: what oracle version do you use?

Comment: Hi Sayan. There's a problem I'm working on that requires this. For now, I think having January 1, 2020 as starting point would be helpful. I am using Oracle version 19. Thank you for your willingness to help! Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what about end date?

Comment: For now, having Feb 29, 2020 as end date would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with start_params as (
    select
        to_date('01/01/2020', 'MM/DD/YYYY') as start_date,
        60 numdays
    from dual
),
colors as (
    select to_date('1/28/2020 09:29', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') as color_date, 'red' as color,  1 color_count from dual union
    select to_date('2/3/2020 07:04', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') as color_date,  'red' as color,  5 color_count from dual union
    select to_date('2/6/2020 12:11', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') as color_date,  'red' as color,  11 color_count from dual union
    select to_date('2/11/2020 17:15', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') as color_date,  'red' as color,  4 color_count from dual union
    select to_date('2/15/2020 03:46', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') as color_date,  'red' as color,  6 color_count from dual union
    select to_date('1/16/2020 14:52', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') as color_date, 'blue' as color, 7 color_count from dual union
    select to_date('1/19/2020 22:30', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') as color_date, 'blue' as color, 32 color_count from dual union
    select to_date('1/23/2020 05:17', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') as color_date, 'blue' as color, 16 color_count from dual union
    select to_date('1/28/2020 18:35', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') as color_date, 'blue' as color, 24 color_count from dual union
    select to_date('1/31/2020 15:38', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') as color_date, 'blue' as color, 41 color_count from dual union
    select to_date('2/2/2020 16:01', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') as color_date,  'blue' as color, 11 color_count from dual
),
upd_colors as (
    select
        (select start_date from start_params) color_date,
        color,
        min(color_count) keep(dense_rank first order by color_date) color_count
    from colors
    group by color
    union
    select trunc(color_date), color, color_count from colors
),
dates as (
    select dat, color
    from (
        select start_date + numtodsinterval(level-1, 'DAY') dat
        from start_params connect by level <= numdays
    ), (select distinct color from colors)
)
select d.dat, d.color,
    nvl(c.color_count, lag(c.color_count ignore nulls) over (partition by d.color order by d.dat)) color_count
from dates d, upd_colors c
where c.color_date(+) = d.dat
  and c.color(+) = d.color
order by color, dat
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=01211076ed2088e0f9155a5097560e1b)

Comment: Replaced "union all" with "union", otherwise the rows can double if colors initially contains data for start_date

Answer (score 2):

That's it:

```sql
with tbl as (
    select to_date('1/28/2020 09:29', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') as color_date, 'red' as color,  1 color_count from dual union
    select to_date('2/3/2020 07:04', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') as color_date,  'red' as color,  5 color_count from dual union
    select to_date('2/6/2020 12:11', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') as color_date,  'red' as color,  11 color_count from dual union
    select to_date('2/11/2020 17:15', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') as color_date,  'red' as color,  4 color_count from dual union
    select to_date('2/15/2020 03:46', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') as color_date,  'red' as color,  6 color_count from dual union
    select to_date('1/16/2020 14:52', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') as color_date, 'blue' as color, 7 color_count from dual union
    select to_date('1/19/2020 22:30', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') as color_date, 'blue' as color, 32 color_count from dual union
    select to_date('1/23/2020 05:17', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') as color_date, 'blue' as color, 16 color_count from dual union
    select to_date('1/28/2020 18:35', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') as color_date, 'blue' as color, 24 color_count from dual union
    select to_date('1/31/2020 15:38', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') as color_date, 'blue' as color, 41 color_count from dual union
    select to_date('2/2/2020 16:01', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') as color_date,  'blue' as color, 11 color_count from dual
)
-- get first and last dates:
,first_record(color_date,color,color_count, end_date) as (
   select
      trunc(min(color_date),'yyyy'), -- 1st of Jan of min(color_date) or use own hardcoded date
      min(color) keep(dense_rank first order by color_date), 
      min(color_count) keep(dense_rank first order by color_date),
      last_day(max(color_date)) as end_date -- last dat of max(color_date) or you can replace it with own hardcoded date
   from tbl
)
-- add them into the data from tbl:
,data as (
   select color_date,color,color_count from first_record
   union
   select * from tbl   
)
-- generating all dates:
,dates_generator as (
    select color_date+N as color_date from first_record, xmltable('0 to 100000' columns N int path '.') x
    where x.n <= end_date-color_date
)
-- simple left join:
select 
   g.color_date
  ,nvl(d.color, lag(color ignore nulls) over(order by g.color_date)) as color
  ,nvl(d.color_count, lag(color_count ignore nulls) over(order by g.color_date)) as color_count
from dates_generator g
     left join data d
          on g.color_date=d.color_date
/
```

Comment: Thanks again for your help Sayan! One question. I don't see a `COLOR_COUNT` column in the solution. Can you help me with that one?